# Is the sort order used in a WHERE condition with OR

Tags: abap

If I have an internal table `lt_itab`, with type SORTED by `werks matnr` and , does this LOOP do a binary search?

```
LOOP AT lt_itab INTO ls_itab
    WHERE ( werks = space OR werks = '*' ).
```

Or does the `OR` force a linear scan?

Comment: I don't know abap but I believe it has functionality (common to many databases) to `explain` query plans. Are you able to get the database to tell you how it's going to execute it?

Comment: This is not a db request

Comment: The table is sorted with key `werks` and you are checking whether the key is initial or asterisk? Is it a non unique key?

Comment: @Jagger it is completely irrelevant, but I edited the question, to avoid sidetracks

Answer (score 2):

It should be a linear scan.

As on `FILTER` operator, [Multiple comparisons](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenconstructor_expr_filter_table.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@) can be joined using `AND` only in the `WHERE`, in my opinion, to make sure it is binary search.

And in the case of a hash key, precisely one comparison expression for each key component. The only relational operator allowed for `op` is `=`, also is to make sure search is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

## It is a linear scan

I have built a small test program with a 100 million rows. The OR makes the LOOP about 150 times slower.

Answer (score 2):

From the official documentation:

> If no explicit table key name is specified after USING KEY, the order
>   in which the rows are read depends on the table category as follows:
>
> **Standard tables and sorted tables.**  The rows are read by ascending row
>   numbers in the primary table index. In each loop pass, the system
>   field sy-tabix contains the row number of the current row in the
>   primary table index.
>
> **Hashed tables.**  The rows are processed in the order in which they were
>   inserted in the table, and by the sort order used after the statement
>   SORT. In each loop pass, the system field sy-tabix contains the value
>   0.
>
> The loop continues to run until all the table rows that meet the cond
>   condition have been read or until it is exited with a statement. If no
>   appropriate rows are found or if the internal table is blank, the loop
>   is not run at all.

The loop doesn't do a binary search, since it's not searching, but looping, i.e. iterating over every row in `lt_itab`.

https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abaploop_at_itab.htm